# Computer shuts off during installation of Ubuntu

Tags: system-installation

I'm planning on switching from Windows 10 to Linux. After downloading the latest Ubuntu desktop and mounting it into a bootable usb. I boot it up and the gui wasn't there it's just plain gray text over black screen and I went on to continue with install Ubuntu choice and the screen goes black and after a few seconds the entire computer shuts off. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Check your bios for secure boot, if it's on turn it off and then try again...

Comment: When you boot you have the option of "check disc for defects" which will verify your download (of ISO) was perfect, as well as the write-to-install-media (be it cd/dvd/thumb-drive).  This option is what i'd perform; as if it doesn't complete successfully prior steps (download, write-to-media) were faulty & you'll be wasting your time trying to solve issues.  You also didn't tell us what release you are trying to use.